# PromptDialog not asking in Dialog class

Tags: c#, botframework

I've been doing a bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework in C# and I encountered a problem.

The problem is that when I call "PromptDialog" to get a String from the user, in this case a password, it doesn't ask for it, it opens the "Password" method and crashes when trying to obtain that String.

Thanks for your help!

*The class extends LUISDialog*

`PromptDialog.Text(context, resume: Password, prompt: "Enter password:");`

LUIS Intent null:

```
[LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        Boolean PassLogin;
        Start(context, activity); //Does this need to be awaited?
        if (!context.UserData.TryGetValue<Boolean>("PassLogin", out PassLogin)) PassLogin = false;
        if (PassLogin)
        {
            var act = await activity;
            if (act.Conversation.IsGroup != null && act.Conversation.IsGroup.Value)
            {
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            }
            else
            {
                await Nothing(context, activity, result);
            }
        }
        else context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

Start Method. The Start method is called by every intent from LUIS.

```
public async Task Start(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
    {
        Boolean PassLogin, start;
        if (!context.UserData.TryGetValue<Boolean>("PassLogin", out PassLogin))
        {
            PassLogin = false;
            context.UserData.SetValue<Boolean>("PassLogin", PassLogin);
        }
        if (!context.UserData.TryGetValue<Boolean>("start", out start))
        {
            start = true;
        }
        if (start)
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(context, resume: Password, prompt: "Enter password:");
            await context.PostAsync("Something"); //This prints out before going to password.
        }
        await GetKey(context, activity);
    }

private async Task Password(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<String> argument)
    {
        var response = await argument;
        if (response=="test")
        {
            context.UserData.SetValue<Boolean>("PassLogin", true);
            await context.PostAsync("Correct Password.");
            if (context.UserData.Get<Boolean>("PassLogin"))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Welcome");
                context.UserData.SetValue<Boolean>("start", false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.UserData.SetValue<Boolean>("PassLogin", false);
            await context.PostAsync("Incorrect password.");
        }
        context.Wait(MessageReceived); //Does this need to be here? (Tried with and without.)
    }
```

This is what the error says:

```
Exception: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNextException: invalid next: Wait: Poll Object for ThunkStart.Rest have Object at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop&lt;C&gt;-PollAsync&gt;d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult() at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog1.&lt;ResumeAsync&gt;d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume1.<Rest>d4.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d19.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame1.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop&lt;C&gt;-PollAsync&gt;d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d13.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-PollAsync>d19.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d21`1.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync&gt;d__21.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync&gt;d__31.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d3`1.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.&lt;Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync&gt;d__51.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Added details on the error.

Comment: Can you also add the method that is calling the PromptDialog.Text? I think the issue is there.

Comment: Added the Start method.

Comment: Does the GetKey method call to context.Wait?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Do you want me to include it? I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Comment the post async and the getkey method after the call to the dialog and let me know if it works please...

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing the new code, first issue Start is not being awaited. Second issue you shouldn't put code After the call to PromptDialog... and finally...all the code after the Start call must be in the Passpord resume after method. Let me know and I will post the formal answer

Comment: excellent, I posted the formal answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, there are a few issues that would have to be solved:

1. The call to the `Start` method must be awaited
2. There shouldn't be code after the call to `PromptDialog.Text`. That code is starting a new dialog that will continue in the `ResumeAfter` method once it's done
3. All the code after the `Start` call seems to depend on the `ResumeAfter` of the Prompt so it should be moved there.